# Passing a large file to Celery for processing isn't working

Tags: python, celery

I want to save a file to AWS S3 and I am using Celery because I don't want to wait until the function finishes writing the file. The problem is when I send it to a Celery function I can see that it's not the same size in my AWS file storage compare to the actual file size.

this is when I am sending it to the Celery function:

```
file_to_put = str(file_to_put) # because you can't send an object to celery fun
write_file_aws.delay(file_full_name, file_to_put)
```

the Celery function itself:

```
@celery.task(name="write_file_to_aws")
def write_file_aws(file_full_name, file_to_put):
    file_to_put = bytearray(file_to_put)
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    s3.Object(BUCKET, file_full_name).put(Body=file_to_put)
    return "Request sent!"
```

This is when the file size is smaller than what it should be (for e.g 1kb instead of 22kb in pictures is even 710kb instead of 230) and the file itself is just gibberish. Why would it happen? is it because of me turning it to a `string`? if it is what else can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're serializing a large file and passing it as an argument to the function. 
I assume you're using EC2. So you could instead store the file to the AWS EC2's instance storage or EBS first (they're faster to write to then S3). Then pass the "path" to this file as an argument to the Celery function call. The Celery worker will then copy the file to S3.

i.e. this:

```
def write_file_aws(file_full_name, file_to_put)
```

will become:

```
def write_file_aws(file_full_name, path_to_local_file)
```

Here's a primer on AWS EC2 storage options: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Storage.html

Comment: Are they really that fast? I mean it takes to S3 upload 1.5 min for 16mb file how long would it take to EC2?

Comment: Haven't used AWS for a while, but instance storage seems like a SSD attached locally to the EC2 instance, while S3 data goes via an API to a whole different storage mechanism.

Comment: Would you say saving it for a limited time in redis is better?

Comment: You can use that too. Any fast access storage is fine. I think using instance storage is as simple as writing a file to a temp directory on the server. but your choice if you're comfortable with Redis.

Comment: I am. I just want to do the fastest way

Comment: Well, I wouldn't use Redis for storing temp files. That's what local instance storage is meant for. It'll be fastest I guess. I'm not an AWS expert though.

Comment: Wait why would I need to copy the files if I have access to them in EC2? I can just get the files in EC2 why would I move it to S3

Comment: Well you can read about S3 and EBS and decide what's good for your use case. S3 is cheaper I guess, and gives publicly accessible URLs. While EBS is like a hard disk for your EC2. Not very sure.

Comment: Can you try and answer my new question maybe?

Answer (score 1):

For **valid reasons** (in short - the task arguments are stored in backend memory and if the object is large it may cause memory errors) you can't pass large objects to your Celery tasks. Instead you pass a reference to wherever the Celery task can access that large object. If it is a file, then put it on a shared filesystem (NFS for an example) accessible by all Celery nodes, and pass file name (and maybe a path if that makes it easier to you).

Comment: I don't really understand how I can put it in a shareable file system. My problem is I don't want the user to wait for the file to be written into AWS. I don't want to read the file, just write it, and writing it takes time. How can I get something that is just in a variable in python? Note: I am not in localhost, I am using Heroku so I can't just do `wb`. the main reason that I want to use Celery is because of the 30-second limit that Heroku has on a task to load.

Comment: Something created the file - can you make that part of the task too?

Comment: Yeah I am sending the file over python-client. I think I found a solution - store the file in Redis. What do you think? Is there a better idea?